# Is it possible to find all objects that are not related in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have inherited an Azure Data Factory solution in my new job. It has been worked on by at least 6 different BI developers. I'm currently busy with cleaning up my Azure Data Factory, fixing version control, and making sure that all my three environments are the same.

Some objects seem obsolete to me. To check if it is obsolete, I go over to the portal, and check the objects Properties if it is related to another object.

[image: Property of ADF object]

If not, it is a confirmation for me that the object is not (yet) used and I can safely remove it from the solution.

Is there an easier way than checking each object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out and wanted to share it here. It is possible to check the "orphaned" objects in an ADF instance, however not directly from the UI. Paul Andrew has [an excellent blogpost](https://mrpaulandrew.com/2020/11/09/best-practices-for-implementing-azure-data-factory-auto-checker-script-v0-1/) about his script that is able to check your ADF code against his best practices. The relevant checks for me are:

- Pipeline(s) without any triggers attached. Directly or indirectly.
- Dataset(s) not used by any other resource.
- Trigger(s) not used by any other resource.
- Linked Service(s) not used by any other resource.

The last check can also be done via UI, see @AbhishekKhandave-MT answer.

Step 1: Export ARM template to a local folder, and unzip it
[image: export ARM template]

Step 2: Download Paul Andrews PowerShell script from [here](https://github.com/mrpaulandrew/BlogSupportingContent/blob/master/Best%20Practices%20for%20Implementing%20Azure%20Data%20Factory%20-%20Auto%20Checker%20Script%20v0.1/ADF%20Checker%20Script%20v0.1.ps1)

Step 3: Open the script and replace the $ARMTemplateFilePath variable with the path to your ADF ARM template. If you want to check out the details, change the `$VerboseOutput` variable to `$true`

Step 4: Run the script and check the results.

Here are my results, so 58 datasets are not used by any other resource.

[image: Results]

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. After 48 hours, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no other way to find whether object is used(yet) or not.

But you can check number of datasets linked with a single linked service as shown in below screenshot.

**Manage > Linked Services**

[image]

Click on number in Related column.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is indeed a way to check if a Linked Services is related to one or more objects within Azure Data Factory. Too bad that we cannot check for orphaned objects.